# How to assigning seprate string values to other variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to assign string value to another variable. there is 3 values of string and I want assign each value to that variable. below is the code

**for getting product id's**

```
 this.filteredProductList.forEach(prod => {
    this.productId = prod.productId;
    console.log("this.productID", this.productId);
   })
```

//OUTPUT FOR THIS

this.productID P202012182259507444

this.productID P202012182235573226

this.productID P202012182230539317

**For assigning that product id's to one varible after clicking on that particular Id.**

```
showTooltip(visible) {
  console.log("inside tooltip");
  console.log("this.productID from showtooltip fun", this.productId);
}
```

//HERE I WANT ALL THREE VALUES BUT GOT ONLY LAST VALUE ON EVERY CLICK. I CLIKED 3 TIMES. WE HAD 3 ID"S ABOVE SAME ID's WANT HERE.

//BUT GETTING OUTPUT FOR THIS.

inside tooltip

this.productID from showtooltip fun P202012182230539317

inside tooltip

this.productID from showtooltip fun P202012182230539317

inside tooltip

this.productID from showtooltip fun P202012182230539317

**//OUPUT is same for each click**

**Below is the html code**

```
   <button class="btn1" href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="showTooltip(true)" data-toggle="modal"
   data-target="#head01" aria-modal="true">Are you eligible to apply online?</button>
```

Please let me know how I can get correct value on click.

Comment: The code is behaving as you have written it... `this.filteredProductList.forEach(...)`. Inside that, `this.productId` is just one variable and you are setting the same variable in the loop. So after the loop finishes, that variable will have the value from the last element of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you assign a new productId to the existing productId by doing this:

```
this.productId = prod.productId;
```

So what you want to do is maybe create a new array before calling your function like so:

```
this.productIdArray = [];
```

And instead of reassigning your productId push them into the productIdArray

```
this.productIdArray.push(prod.productId);
```

Then inside of your function do the following:

```
showTooltip(visible) {
      console.log("inside tooltip");

 this.productIdArray.forEach((id) => {
      console.log("this.productID from showtooltip fun", id);
 )}
}
```

Comment: Hi @DarkZerone thank you for your answer. I got the solution for that. I passed product id from html button click function (click)="showTooltip(productId)" and same Id passed to function showTooltip(id) and access that.

Comment: Hey, I am glad to hear you figured it out. Good luck with your project :)